# How to send a JSONObject into a Retrofit API call Android

Tags: android, api, retrofit, retrofit2

I have implemented the first time Retrofit in my Android code and am facing the following issues:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding. (parameter #1)

I have implemented my code like below:

```
public interface APIService {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/")
    @Headers({
        "domecode: axys",
        "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8"
    })
    Call<JsonObject> sendLocation(@Body JsonObject jsonObject);
}


public class ApiUtils {

    static String tempUrl = "http://192.168.16.114:8092/api/v1/location/tsa/";
    public static APIService getAPIService() {

        return RetrofitClient.getClient(tempUrl).create(APIService.class);
    }
}

public class RetrofitClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
        if(retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

}
```

Passing the value to an API call

```
JsonObject postParam = new JsonObject();
try {
    postParam.addProperty(Fields.ID, "asdf");
}

Call<JsonObject> call = apiService.sendLocation(postParam);
call.enqueue(
    new Callback<JsonObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
            Log.d("response", "Getting response from server: " + response);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("response", "Getting response from server: " + t);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Don't give the callback `apiService.sendLocation(jsonObject.enqueue(new Callback<JSONObject>(){ ... });`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are using the Android internal JSON APIs. You need to use Gson's classes instead.

```
Call<JsonObject> sendLocation(@Body JsonObject jsonObject);
```

Hence the import statement

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
```

Another error is passing the *Callback* as a parameter to the request

```
Call<JsonObject> call = apiService.sendLocation(jsonObject);
call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
   @Override
   public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
      Log.d("response", "Getting response from server: "+response);
   }

   @Override
   public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
      Log.d("response", "Getting response from server: " + t);
   }
});
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding. (parameter #1)I have imported import com.google.gson.JsonObject; and changed and cross checked but getting same error :

Comment: You need to change `JSONObject` to `JsonObject`

Comment: please check my updated code :

 JsonObject postParam = new JsonObject();
                try {
                    postParam.addProperty(Fields.ID, "asdf")
                    postParam.addProperty(Fields._ID_OLD, "asdf");
                    postParam.addProperty(Fields.LATI, "asdf");
                    postParam.addProperty(Fields.LON, "asdf")
                    postParam.addProperty(Fields.OR_IDS, "asdf");
                } catch (JsonIOException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }

Comment: You don't need this argument `Callback<JSONObject> callback`

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time, i have updated the code as u said, and again am facing the same problem , is it because of  JsonObject postParam = new JsonObject();
            try {
                postParam.addProperty(Fields.ID, "asdf");
                }

Comment: I have updated the question as u said , please check it

Comment: `@FormUrlEncoded` can't be used where you are sending a `@Body`

Comment: I just removed the @FormUrlEncoded and using as u said,its not throwing any error but on response is not coming

Comment: That's  an error in either the url or the server. Please mark the answer as correct if it already answer your original question .