# How to pass json object with array on retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, jsonobjectrequest

When I send request through postman as row request(Json) I am getting the success response, But from my android device its not getting success.

Postman Request
[image]

Here is My Android code,

Interface `ApiService.Class`

```
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("api/ShopData/AddProduct")
    Call<AddNewProductResponse> addNewProduct(@Header("Authorization") String authorization, @Body JsonObject jsonObject);
```

Class `ApiClient.Class`

```
public static Call<AddNewProductResponse> addNewProduct(String token, JsonObject jsonObject) {
    token = "Bearer " + token;
    Call<AddNewProductResponse> call = apiService.addNewProduct(token, jsonObject);
    return call;
}
```

API Call

```
    private void addNewProductToServer(JsonObject jsonObject) {
        String token = AppSettings.getInstance(getActivity()).getStringValue(PrefKeys.token);
        if (token != null && jsonObject != null) {
            ApiClient.addNewProduct(token, jsonObject).enqueue(new Callback<AddNewProductResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<AddNewProductResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<AddNewProductResponse> response) {
                    if (response != null && response.body() != null) {
                        if (response.body().getMessage().getCode() == 1) {
                            showProductAddedSuccessDialog();
                        } else
                            Helper.showAlertDialogOK(getActivity(), Helper.getErrorMessages(response.body().getMessage().getCode()));
                    } else
                        Helper.showServerErrorDialog(getActivity());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<AddNewProductResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                   Helper.showServerErrorDialog(getActivity());
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Create Request JsonObject,

```
        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
        JsonArray images = new JsonArray();
        try {
            if (productImage != null) {
                JsonObject imgObject = new JsonObject();
                imgObject.addProperty("attachment", productImage.getAttachment());
                imgObject.addProperty("position", 1);
                images.add(imgObject);
            }

            jsonObject.addProperty("name", edtTxtProductName.getText().toString().trim());
            jsonObject.addProperty("short_description", edtTxtShortDescription.getText().toString().trim());
            jsonObject.addProperty("full_description", edtTxtLongDescription.getText().toString().trim());
            jsonObject.addProperty("sku", edtTxtSku.getText().toString().trim());
            jsonObject.addProperty("stock_quantity", Integer.parseInt(edtTxtStockQuantity.getText().toString().trim()));
            jsonObject.addProperty("price", Float.parseFloat(edtTxtPrice.getText().toString().trim()));
            jsonObject.addProperty("images", String.valueOf(images));
            addNewProductToServer(jsonObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: try it with `jsonObject.toString()` while passing

Comment: @RaviRupareliya I need to pass Body as String right?

Comment: Yes, inshort your jsonObject

Comment: Why not just use PoJo with GSON?

Comment: @RaviRupareliya No its not working, I Modified like,
----ApiService.Class-----
Call<AddNewProductResponse> addNewProduct(Header("Authorization") String authorization, Body String jsonObject)
----ApiClient.Class------
apiService.addNewProduct(token, jsonObject.toString());

Comment: @AntonA. First I Tried with JSONObject, Then I check with JsonObject

Comment: @SHIDHIN.T.S I mean GSON lib. You do not need to write code. Just use pojo with annotations. Also add gson serializer to retrofit initialization

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to send JSONObject into retrofit API call android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42529732/how-to-send-jsonobject-into-retrofit-api-call-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the line

```
jsonObject.addProperty("images", String.valueOf(images));
```

by

```
jsonObject.add("images", images);
```

Comment: Let me try this.

Comment: So you have an other error, but this is the right way to add a JsonArray to a JsonObject.

Comment: This solved my problem. There was "\n" on Base64 Image string. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Create your ModelClass and set your values

```
public class ModelClass {

@SerializedName("name")
private String name = "";
@SerializedName("short_description")
private String shortDesc = "";
@SerializedName("full_description")
private String fullDescription = "";
@SerializedName("sku")
private String sku = "";
@SerializedName("stock_quantity")
private int qty = 0;
@SerializedName("price")
private double price = 0.0;
@SerializedName("images")
private ArrayList<ImageModel> imageList;


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getShortDesc() {
    return shortDesc;
}

public void setShortDesc(String shortDesc) {
    this.shortDesc = shortDesc;
}

public String getFullDescription() {
    return fullDescription;
}

public void setFullDescription(String fullDescription) {
    this.fullDescription = fullDescription;
}

public String getSku() {
    return sku;
}

public void setSku(String sku) {
    this.sku = sku;
}

public int getQty() {
    return qty;
}

public void setQty(int qty) {
    this.qty = qty;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public ArrayList<ImageModel> getImageList() {
    return imageList;
}

public void setImageList(ArrayList<ImageModel> imageList) {
    this.imageList = imageList;
}
}
```

Create your ImageModel class

```
private class ImageModel {
@SerializedName("attachment")
private String attachment;
@SerializedName("position")
private int position;

public String getAttachment() {
    return attachment;
}

public void setAttachment(String attachment) {
    this.attachment = attachment;
}

public int getPosition() {
    return position;
}

public void setPosition(int position) {
    this.position = position;
}
}
```

and pass your class with your retrofit implementation

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("api/ShopData/AddProduct")
Call<AddNewProductResponse> addNewProduct(@Header("Authorization") String authorization, @Body ModelClass jsonObject);
```

Hope this helps you.