# Set header in retrofit http post request

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp

I have a retrofit interface (kotlin):

```
interface Api {
     @POST("updates")
     fun getDetails(@Header("Authorization") token: Token,
                    @Body body: RequestBody): Single<ResponseObject>
}
```

When I call it like this (in java),

```
List<String> apps = Arrays.asList("app1", "app2");
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
RequestBody requestBody;
try {
    jsonObject.put("apps", new JSONArray(apps));
}
catch(JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
requestBody = RequestBody.create(jsonObject.toString(), MediaType.get("application/json"));
api.getDetails(token, requestBody); // works
```

It works and returns the proper data.

My problem is that I don't want to create a new RequestBody object for each call, so instead of receiving a RequestBody, I want my interface to receive the JSON Object. When I try this however,

```
interface Api {
     @POST("updates")
     fun getDetails(@Header("Authorization") token: Token,
                    @Header("Content-Type") type: String,
                    @Body body: JSONObject): Single<ResponseObject>
}

api.getDetails(token, "application/json", jsonObject); // does not work
```

it returns with a `retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.HttpException: HTTP 400` error.

How do I make this http call with just the JSONObject? I think there may be something wrong with how I am specifying the Content-Type, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Try this it may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/q/42529732/7592063

Comment: Your title has difference with your problem u want to set `header` without `@header` or u want to change body from `requestBody` to `jsonObject`?

Comment: @Rajnishsuryavanshi that link did help me, thanks a lot. I switched from JSONObject to JsonObject and the request works without even using a special header.